# How to render two screens in Janrain

Tags: javascript, janrain

I am trying to implement editprofile render screen twice in a same page but found that its only render first screen and then exit.

Is it possible to use to two screens in same page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the Janrain Registration Widget so my answer is based off of this assumption.

While the Registration widget is highly customizable this scenario (rendering multiple "screens" at the same time) is not supported.  It is not exactly clear why you want to render the same edit profile screen in two places on the same page.  I think that your actual requirements may not be that simple.  Perhaps you want to show part of the form in one area and part of the form in another.

I would recommend that you simply hide the editprofile screen/form with css and create your own separate forms for what ever you are trying to do.  You can then update the Janrain editprofile form fields and submit them using client-side javascript as needed.  This method would be much easier to implement and require less customization of the Janrain Registration widget.